# Asian growth charts

Tags: growth

The [WHO growth standards](http://www.who.int/childgrowth/en/) are applicable worldwide and designed to suit all ethnic groups, but given that genetics play an important part in stature, can parents of Asian children rely on different growth charts that are specific to the growth patterns of Asian kids? In particular, does anyone know of existing growth standards (with percentiles) for Chinese or Japanese children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly. The genes matter. If I compare my kid's growth with American's I'll never consider my kid as a normal kid in weight and height! There is where the role of **local government** comes. And, we should follow this because when they prepare such charts, they take utmost care and derive data from a lot of research and zillions of evidences.

I'd rather recommend going for a regional kid's growth charge i.e. country-wise as compared to the growth chart for continents. That's because Asia is too big! The growth that you see in India is certainly different than in China/Japan. This includes the life expectancy, weight, height or things the like.

I found it for you.

[image]

[image]

**Very useful [PDF download here.](http://www.iccg.ie/documents/uploaded/FCC%20Growth%20Charts.pdf)**

I'm not sure about Japanese growth chart as I could not find it. However, I recommend asking this on any local government website (or local search engine for that sake? Say Baidu?) and you'll get the Japanese one also.

Comment: Thank you, great find! It's old, though, so I wonder if different ones can be found in China. It would be great to compile a directory of growth charts per country/region and even per medical condition (for example there are specific charts for preterm babies and Down syndrome).

Comment: Be mindful that some governments release data they want the populace to follow, not necessarily based on data.  Well researched and academically-reviewed data is more reliable.  Governments aren't authorities on much.